# Is there some kind of "git init -f"?

Tags: git

I want to clone a remote repo (of a framework, for instance) and then init my own blank repository on top of it. Is there an easy way to acomplish that? (like `git init -f` would be if it was real)

I know I can remove `.git` and then init again. I was just wondering if there was a better way. thanks (:

Comment: I'm a little curious as to *why* you'd want to do this, would you mind extrapolating?

Comment: @jeremiahd just wanted to make an alias like "git framework" that clones a repo and reinitializes it. But it seems like i can put shell commands in aliases, so i guess i'm fine without it (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, but it's a bit messy. You essentially will have to reset where and how the original project is tracked - but you can preserve the history, which is nice.

Check out [this link](http://www.programblings.com/2008/07/21/setting-up-a-long-term-fork-with-git/) for ideas on how to fork an existing git repo. If there's an easier way to maintain the history but otherwise divorce two git projects, I'm not aware of it.

Personally, unless you really want to preserve the history of the original repository, I'd just nuke the .git folder and re-init :)